# Laravel Vapor Custom Logs to Amazon AWS Cloudwatch as JSON

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, laravel-vapor

By default Laravel Vapor pushes the `laravel.log` file to strerr output. Which is the picked up by Lambda and thrown to Cloudwatch. Quite hard to look through unless you are looking via the Vapor UI.
Look for an easy way to do this and push them directly to Cloudwatch (with multiple files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly added this awesome Library

```
composer require maxbanton/cwh
```

Then add this to your log config...

```
        'cloudwatch' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'via' => \App\Logging\CloudWatchLoggerFactory::class,
            'formatter' => Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter::class,
            'cloudwatch_stream_name' => 'laravel',
            'sdk' => [
                'region' => 'eu-west-1',
                'version' => 'latest',
                'credentials' => [
                    'key' => env('AWS_CW_ACCESS'),
                    'secret' => env('AWS_CW_SECRET')
                ]
            ],
            'retention' => 730,
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],
```

You'll need to add `AWS_CW_ACCESS` and `AWS_CW_SECRET` keys for an IAM user with access to Cloudwatch.

Then add `App/Logging/CloudWatchLoggerFactory.php` with the following contents..

```
<?php

namespace App\Logging;

use Aws\CloudWatchLogs\CloudWatchLogsClient;
use Maxbanton\Cwh\Handler\CloudWatch;
use Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter;
use Monolog\Logger;

class CloudWatchLoggerFactory
{
    /**
     * Create a custom Monolog instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $config
     * @return \Monolog\Logger
     */
    public function __invoke(array $config)
    {
        $sdkParams = $config["sdk"];
        $tags = $config["tags"] ?? [ ];
        $name = $config["name"] ?? 'cloudwatch';
        
        // Instantiate AWS SDK CloudWatch Logs Client
        $client = new CloudWatchLogsClient($sdkParams);
        
        // Log group name, will be created if none
        $groupName = config('app.name') . '-' . config('app.env');

        // Log stream name, will be created if none
        // $streamName = config('app.hostname');
        $streamName = $config["cloudwatch_stream_name"];

        // Days to keep logs, 14 by default. Set to `null` to allow indefinite retention.
        $retentionDays = $config["retention"];
        // Instantiate handler (tags are optional)
        $handler = new CloudWatch($client, $groupName, $streamName, $retentionDays, 10000, $tags);
        $handler->setFormatter(new JsonFormatter());
        // Create a log channel
        $logger = new Logger($name);
        // Set handler
        $logger->pushHandler($handler);
        //$logger->pushProcessor(new CompanyLogProcessor()); //Use this if you want to adjust the JSON output using a log processor
        return $logger;
    }
}
```

You can then use that as any log... Ie `Log::channel('cloudwatch')->info('hey');`

To force the default laravel.log to here AND show in vapor just add this as a stack

```
        'vapor' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['stderr', 'cloudwatch'],
            'ignore_exceptions' => false,
        ],
```

Then set `logging.default` setting to `vapor` in your envvars.

If you want additional logging channels just copy the `cloudwatch` channel setting with a new one and make sure you adjust the `cloudwatch_stream_name`.

Thanks to the other answer I found on Stackoverflow helping me get to here. I wanted to log this directly under answer for Laravel Vapor as I imagine many others will get stuck trying to do this!

Comment: Following on from this we didn't like such approach. It seems that logs to STDOUT (default) are picked up to cloudwatch. So we just adjusted our code so that we have a "log" in the json at the top level then just used cloudwatch insights to query it by log type instead of viewing them oldschool in cloudwatch logs. Hope this helps, much better and worked with Laravel Vapor much nicer.